# Is it possible to translate TypeScript declaration doc comments as they appear in hover info and suggestion descriptions in VS Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I don't speak English, I would like to know if it's possible to get translated versions of these boxes that appear when hovering the mouse over a declaration and give descriptions / documentation are.

Here's an example of what I'm talking about with the `String.prototype.split()` method:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot is of a suggestion description for a TypeScript type declaration for `String.prototype.split()`, which shows its documentation comment from a lib.d.ts file bundled with TypeScript. You can find the source code for the lib.d.ts files on TypeScript's GitHub repo: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/tree/main/lib.

You'll see there that they do provide translations for TypeScript's compiler's error messages, but I'm not aware of them providing versions of their lib.d.ts files with translated documentation comments.

Much more common on the internet and open source world for web libraries is for English to be used as a lingua franca, which might explain why in my (perhaps limited) experience in web dev, I haven't seen anyone put effort into providing versions of their package files with documentation comments translated to various languages.

So unfortunately, it's not something that [changing your display language setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/locales#_changing-the-display-language) can affect.

This probably extends to more than just web libraries. English is fairly well established as the lingua franca of code at least in the open source world. Most of this hover documentation even for other programming lanugages is pulled from documentation comments, which are usually in English, and as already stated, most libraries don't provide header files / documentation sources with translated documentation comments. At least- not that I've observed in my limited experience in the programming world. I'd be happy to be pointed to counterexamples, though!