# How do I change the hover or tooltip language to Spanish in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, hover, tooltip

When I hover over a function, class, or variable, I get information about that element, such as its type, parameters, and documentation. I would like to see it, but in Spanish, to learn more about the language. I use python

Change the language to the editor and restart but it still appears in English.

Comment: what programming language are you writing in? Are you using any extensions for programming language support? the answer can depend on the programming language. Ex. for TypeScript: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75377287/11107541

Answer (score 0):

This is related to doc string

[image]

However, you can modify the language of vscode, and its own setting prompts will be displayed in the set language

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Configure Display Language`

[image]